# Loop through option values detect selected value

Tags: php, html

Any ideas on if and how I can use Mysqli and queries in combination with a PHP switch statement to populate textboxes based on which option of an HTML select box is currently selected? So far I have only been able to get a textbox populated on the initial page load ONLY, and this was ONLY through the default case of the PHP switch statement. My work so far is as follows:

```
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name)

switch("Not sure what to put here")
{
    case "corresponds with first <option> of select box but not sure how to do this" :
       $result = $mysql->query(---placeholder for SQL query---);

       while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
       {
          $queryResult = $row->---placeholder for column name---;
       }
       $textboxValue = $queryResult;
       break;
}
```

Comment: doesn't really have anything to do with mysql. Are you posting this information to your page or is it an AJAX call?

Comment: It does have to do with mysql. The textbox gets populated with data from the DB, and I'm not using AJAX.

Comment: @programm3r - you're going to have to add more information, like example output.

Comment: You can use php's `echo '<html elements>';` to shape your html page based off of your mysqli results. For example, `if($row['isActive'] == 0) { echo '<b> isActive value is 0</b>'; } else { echo '<i>isActive value is 1</i>'; }`

Comment: @andrewsi The only output is just a textbox that gets populated on initial page load ONLY. I'm not sure what else you want me to provide.

Comment: @le_garry I know all about the echo command with shaping an HTML page, but I don't see how that helps in regards with dynamically populating the textbox.

Comment: If you want to dynamically set the html content based on what select option is chosen, you should use javascript/jquery with an ajax call to retrieve the data that you need to populate the textbox.

Comment: @le_garry Is there anyway you could provide an example using Javascript with an AJAX call to retrieve the data needed to populate the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will want to use javascript/jquery and an ajax call to a php class that will make database calls and return the data you need to store to the textbox.

Here is an example of an ajax call. You can copy the javascript code and edit it to call your own php class instead.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first (yes, it is w3schools.. but this code gets the job done)

Replace the `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);` link to the php page you want to work with, i.e. `xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=3",true);`

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: in your main page that the user sees and chooses a html select option, that page will contain your ajax call. It will also take the returned data from the ajax call (`xmlhttp.responseText`), and set that to the text of your textbox. You'll want another php page that is a simple php page that the ajax method gets. example, loadTextBox.php , you can add $_GET variables onto the call in ajax, so it could say `loadTextBox.php?id=4`. Use `echo` on the loadTextBox.php page to print out the results, which are returned in the `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: If it is still confusing, follow the second link for the w3schools tutorial with examples.

Comment: I'm confused what goes in the loadTextBox.php page. Are you saying just the script from the w3schools link goes in that page?

Comment: You will want to write php code that executes a mysql query to retrieve data from the database. the data will then be echo'd out on the loadTextBox.php page, which will be returned in the xmlhttp.responseText variable.

Comment: In the loadTextBox.php page I put in the MySQL query stuff. In the main page I changed the onclick part of the select tag to say onclick = loadDoc() and also added the code from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first but changed to loadDoc(). I changed document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; to document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; and changed xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true); to xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=3",true); and tried using 4 too, but the textbox doesn't get populated. Any ideas?

Comment: .innerHTML may work differently in browsers. I recommend using jquery library (or Try using `.value` on the element --> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883673/change-textbox-text-in-javascript)

Comment: Using .value works but before the correct text is populated <!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html> is being displayed, and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: Replacing document.getElementById("textbox").value=xmlhttp.responseText; with var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
doc.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("textbox").value=doc.innerHTML; fixes it

Comment: You are creating a new element by doing that though, if that is fine, then go with it. You could also try .innerText, but Im not sure if all browsers support that. I know that using a jquery call `$("#yourElementId").val("your new text");` works pretty well, but requires using a jquery library.