# Change textbox text (parent page) by another textbox (child page) upon text changing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two .aspx pages named default1.aspx and default2.aspx.
default1.aspx has one textbox named as textbox1 and 
default2.aspx has one textbox named as textbox2.
default1.aspx opens the default2.aspx by using window.showmodaldialog().
Issue is that
While i am changing the text of textbox2, the textbox1 text also gets changed.

Comment: can u plz explain clearly by adding code

Answer (score 1):

Given a function in javascript:

```
function clearOther(which){
 document.getElementById(which).value='';
}
```

this can then be called when you focus on one textbox, passing the id of the other:

```
<input type="text" id="box1" onfocus="clearOther('box2')" />
<input type="text" id="box2" onfocus="clearOther('box1')"  />
```

working example --> http://jsfiddle.net/CwWKn/

or check
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883673/change-textbox-text-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Page A
<input type='text' id='tb'>
var returnedValue = showModalDialog('page2.aspx', window);

//Page B
<input type='text' onkeypress='update(this);'>

function update(Sender) {
    var input = window.dialogArguments.document.getElementById("tb");
    input.value = Sender.value
}
```

Another option is to set window.returnValue in modal dialog and update textbox with returnedValue after dialog is closed.